# How to give permissions to yourself in Azure Active Directory in New Portal Azure? Button "Grant Permission" is missing

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have registered a new app using Power BI Developer and go to Portal Azure and do the following steps:

1. Azure Active Directory
2. App registrations
3. (Tab) Owned applications > Choose my app
   [image]
4. (On the new page) > API Permissions (Choose the permissions)
   [image]
5. **Here is my problem!**
   In the old version of Portal Azure, on the top of the page where I choose de permissions, has a magical wonderful named "**Grant Permissions**", like the following image. This is a example:
   [image]
   But now, on the New Portal Azure, I cannot give User Consent to myself (because I can't find this button), like I do on the previous version of Portal Azure. Someone know where I can find it?
   In the second image has a button named "Grant admin consent for **my company**", I have tried this button with my azure admin but it's not I need, I need "User Consent" not "Admin Consent".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Grant permission** is replaced by **Grant admin consent** on new portal.

The permissions you added don't need admin consent, so when the users login in your application for the first time, they will be asked for consent(user consent). No need to do more steps on azure portal.

[image]

If you don't want the users to grant user consent when they login, you can **grant admin consent** for the whole tenant users on azure portal, the users will not be asked for consent again.

Comment: Thanks for answer Tony. Let me ask you, I have registered those App for I can login in oauth2 and get a token and embed a Power BI report, so, where I should login to "Accept" this "Permissions requested" that you mentioned in that printscreen? Now, I am logining using Postman to get a token using the account of App Owner and getting the following message: "AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '______' named '_____'.

Comment: @D.Watson Yes, you must login to accept the consent for the first time. You can force user consent through a url request. This url will look like `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<client id>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=<Your-Redirect-URI-Https-Encoded>&nonce=1234&resource=<your-resource-Https-encoded>&prompt=consent`

Comment: Hey Tony! I have made some changes on the URL and it works perfectly! On param `resource` I let it `blank`, on param `redirect_uri` I put `http://localhost` and on Portal Azure in the page Authentication I have put `http://localhost` as `Redirect URI` and it works. 
Thanks thanks man! I have spent like 15 hours searching for this and you saved me. Thanks again!